# From a group of numbers to a bigger number R

Tags: r

Using R, is there a way to pass from:

`num [1:4] 1 2 3 4`

to

`num 1234`
?

Comment: `as.numeric(paste(1:4, collapse = ""))` will do

Comment: Just what I needed thank you.

Comment: A purely numeric option is `sum(num*10^(rev(seq_along(num))-1))`

Comment: @MrFlick - for integers < 10.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento. Yes. The `as.numeric()` method will coerce numbers outside the max integer range to doubles and will loose precision, but the numeric method will not. Good point.